# ANCOVA with nlme::gls: Are the slopes different from eachother and from 0?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, ancova, generalized-least-squares

I am trying to do an ANCOVA in R. I am using the  `gls` function of the `nlme` package, because the spread of the residuals increases with the  continuous variable x.

My model is:

`m1 <- gls(y~t+A*B*x,data=data,weights=varPower(form = ~ x),method="ML")`

I want to find out:
1. If the slopes are significantly different to 0
2. If there are significant differences between the slopes.

I fittet the model using ML and wanted to drop terms to find the best model by using `avova(m1,m2)`. The full model was significantly better than a model without the 3-way interaction, therefore I left the model as it is, fitted it with REML and used `anova()` and `summary()`.

I understood that the `summary()` of above model tests whether each term (each combination of A and B) is different to the reference level (in this case A = level A1 and B = level B1). Is this correct?

Only one slope was significant (for A=level A1 and B= level B2), therefore I assume that this slope is different to the others. Similar results were given when using the `lstrends` function from the `lsmeans` package.

I don’t know how to test if the slopes are different to 0.

I could subset  the data for each combination of levels of A and B, build another model and use `summary()` to get coefficients and p-values, but this seems wrong. Is there another solution?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `summary.ref.grid`. You can test against zero or any other specified value in `null`.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Now I'm using the `test()` function of `lsmeans` with `null = 0`. One more question to `lsmeans`results: Why are the estimates for the slopes different, when I'm using `lsmeans` and `summary(m)`?

Comment: Because the regression coefficients are not all slopes. Some of them are differences of slopes.

Comment: Semantics is a remarkable barrier to understanding, sometimes. We think of regression coefficients as slopes - and they are, but then they're not.